# PostParamters in Restful Spring not working

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am having a minimal Spring-based Restful server with the following hopefully public method

```
@RequestMapping("/regUser")
public @ResponseBody String  addUser(   @RequestParam(value="name", required=true)          String username,
                                            @RequestParam(value="email", required=true)         String email,
                                            @RequestParam(value="newsletter", required=true)    String newsletter){

    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setEmail(email);
    newUser.setUsername(username);
    newUser.setReceiveNewsletter(true);;

    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++");
    System.out.println("USER: " + username + " | email: " + email + "  | newsletter: " + newsletter);

    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++");
    userRepo.save(newUser);

    return "true";

}
```

When I open the link in the browser and provide the needed parameters using GET in the URL everything is working perfectly fine. So I assume the problem will be in the following Android part.

I want to call the method above from my Android Device. The user has to enter the needed information in three EditText and press a button for sending everthing to the Restful server.

```
    @Override
    protected UserWrapper doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{
            final String url = params[0];
            RestTemplate tmpl = new RestTemplate();
            tmpl.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            UserWrapper greet = tmpl.getForObject(url, UserWrapper.class);
            for(User usr : greet.getUsers()){
                Log.d("User", "Post - Name: " + String.valueOf(usr.getUsername()));
                Log.d("User", "Post - eMail: " + String.valueOf(usr.getEmail()));
            }
            return greet;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is my Code for sending everything to the server. I did this in an AsyncTask because not blocking the main UI Thread in Android if the server takes a little bit longer.

So, what is happening?
First of all I got the message:

**Error, required field name is not present.**

If I switch form **requiered = true** to **requiered = false**, I got the short message "true" and the server reports the following short message:

```
+++++++++++++++
USER: null | email: null  | newsletter: null
+++++++++++++++
```

How can I send the needed parameters using POST to the server?

Thanks to all of you trying to help!

Comment: You are sending JSON not parameters...

Comment: And how can I change that?

Comment: You cannot with your current setup. Don't map to JSON. Or fix the server to be able to receive JSON instead of parameters.

Comment: Okay. Thanks this is at least a new way to adress this problem..

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks your suggestion helped me to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestions, I've found another tutorial which is doing exactly what I wanted to to

http://johnathanmarksmith.com/spring/java/javaconfig/programming/spring%20java%20configuration/spring%20mvc/web/rest/resttemplate/2013/06/18/how-to-use-spring-resttemplate-to-post-data-to-a-web-service/

Using this tutorial everything is working the way I wanted it to work!

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a Map of params, then call your restfull service.

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
//add params
params.put("name", "the name");
params.put("email", "the email");
params.put("newsletter", "the newsletter");
//call service method

String result = tmpl.getForObject(url, String.class, params);
```

Comment: The map do not make the difference. Same behaviour with the same problems.